# If $\dim(\operatorname{Im}T) = 1$, then $T^2$ is such that exists an $\alpha$ such that $T^2(v) = \alpha v$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V be any vector space e $T\colon V \to V$ a linear transformation. If $\dim(\operatorname{Im}T) = 1$, then $T^{2}$ is such that exists an $\alpha$ such  that $T^2(v) = \alpha v$.

Is this true?

I tried to do this: show that $\dim(\operatorname{Im} T^2) = 1$ or $\dim(\operatorname{Im}T^2) = 0$. To prove that, I proved that $\operatorname{Im}(T^2) \subset \operatorname{Im}(T)$ and then $\dim(\operatorname{Im} T^2) \leq \dim(\operatorname{Im} T) = 1$.

What I am not sure is if this implies that $T^2(v) = \alpha v$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you mean $T^2(v)=\alpha v$ *for all $v\in V$*? This can only be true with $\alpha=0$ and so $T$ nilpotent. Indeed, if $\alpha\ne0$, we have $T^2$ invertible, so also $T$ is invertible and so the hypothesis forces $\dim V=1$. For instance, the map $T\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined on the standard basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ by $T(e_1)=e_1$ and $T(e_i)=0$ for $i=2,\dots,n$ satisfies the hypothesis, but $T^2(e_1)=1e_1$ and $T^2(e_2)=0e_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $ Dim ( Im (T))=1$ than $\forall u,v$ we have $T(v)=\alpha T(u)$ for some scalar $\alpha$,

and $T^2(v)=T(T(v))$

Answer (score 0):

$T$ maps all vectors to a one-dimensional subspace of $V$, in other words: a line in $V$. Because $T$ is linear, that line goes through the origin $0$.

Applying $T$ twice will still result in mapping all vectors to that line.

There is no guarantee that the image vector, which is a multiple of the direction vector of that line, will be a multiple $\alpha$ of all the arguments $v$ to $T^2$ each.

Example: $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $T((x,y)^t) = (0, y)^t$.

Then $\text{Im } T = s \, (0,1)^t$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\text{dim }\text{Im}(T) = 1$.

Then for arbitrary $v \in V$:
$$
T^2(v) = T^2((x,y)^t) = T((0,y)^t) = (0, y)^t \ne \alpha v = (\alpha x, \alpha y)^t
$$